# PYSPARK - how can I get the number of elements that cumulates the 80% participation in a column?

Tags: pyspark

I have a column named "Sales", and another column with the Salesman, so I want to know how many salesmans concentrate the 80% of the sales by each type of sales (A, B, C).

For this example,

```
+---------+------+-----+
|salesman |sales |type |
+---------+-------+----+
|   5     |   9  |    a|
|   8     |  12  |    b|
|   6     |   3  |    b|
|   6     |   1  |    a|
|   1     |   3  |    a|
|   5     |   1  |    b|
|   2     |  11  |    b|
|   4     |   3  |    a|
|   1     |   1  |    b|
|   2     |   3  |    a|
|   3     |   4  |    a|
+---------+------+-----+
```

The result should be:

```
+-----+--------- +
|type |Salesman80|
+-----+----------+
|  a  |    4     |
|  b  |    2     |
+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll find the total sales per type.

join this to the table,

groupby salesman, type to get totals per sales per type,
then use a math trick to get percentage.
You can then chop this table to any percentage you wish with a `where` clause.

```
#create some data

data = spark.range(1 , 1000)
sales = data.select( data.id, floor((rand()*13)).alias("salesman"), floor((rand()*26)+65).alias("type"), floor(rand()*26).alias("sale") )

totalSales = sales.groupby(sales.type)\
  .agg(
   sum(sales.sale).alias("total_sales") 
  )\
  .select( col("*"), expr("chr( type)").alias("type_") ) #fix int to chr

sales.join( totalSales , ["type"] )\
 .groupby("salesman","type_")\
 .agg( (sum("sale")/avg("total_sales")).alias("percentage"), 
  avg("total_sales").alias("total_sales_by_type") #Math trick as the total sum is the same on all types. so average = total sales by type.
 ).show()

+--------+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|salesman|type_|          percentage|total_sales_by_type|
+--------+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
|      10|    H| 0.04710144927536232|              552.0|
|       9|    U| 0.21063394683026584|              489.0|
|       0|    I| 0.09266409266409266|              518.0|
|      11|    K| 0.09683426443202979|              537.0|
|       0|    F|0.027070063694267517|              628.0|
|      11|    F|0.054140127388535034|              628.0|
|       1|    G| 0.08086253369272237|              371.0|
|       5|    N|  0.1693548387096774|              496.0|
|       9|    L| 0.05353728489483748|              523.0|
|       7|    R|0.003058103975535...|              327.0|
|       0|    C| 0.05398457583547558|              389.0|
|       6|    G|  0.1105121293800539|              371.0|
|      12|    A|0.057007125890736345|              421.0|
|       0|    J| 0.09876543209876543|              567.0|
|      11|    B| 0.11337209302325581|              344.0|
|       8|    K| 0.08007448789571694|              537.0|
|       4|    N| 0.06854838709677419|              496.0|
|      11|    H|  0.1358695652173913|              552.0|
|      10|    W| 0.11617312072892938|              439.0|
|       1|    C| 0.06940874035989718|              389.0|
+--------+-----+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean "how many salesmans contribute to the 80% of the total sales per type" and you want the lowest possible number of salesman.

If that is what you meant, you can do this in these steps

1. Calculate the total sales per group
2. Get cumulative sum of sales percentage (sales / total sales)
3. Assign the row number by ordering sales in descending order
4. Take minimum row number where the cumulative sum of sales percentage >= 80% per group

Note this is probably not efficient approach but it produces what you want.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

part_window = Window.partitionBy('type')
order_window = part_window.orderBy(F.desc('sales'))
cumsum_window = order_window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

df = (df.withColumn('total_sales', F.sum('sales').over(part_window)) # Step 1
      .select('*',
          F.sum(F.col('sales') / F.col('total_sales')).over(cumsum_window).alias('cumsum_percent'), # Step 2
          F.row_number().over(order_window).alias('rn')) # Step 3
      .groupby('type')  # Step 4
      .agg(F.min(F.when(F.col('cumsum_percent') >= 0.8, F.col('rn'))).alias('Salesman80')))
```